# Google Spreadsheet. Не удается вызвать метод "getActiveSheet"

Tags: java, google-spreadsheet

По работе необходимо сделать так, чтобы при редактировании ячейки в другую писалась дата редактирования. стандартные формулы СЕГОДНЯ() и ТДАТА() пересчитывают дату при каждом обновлении страницы. Перерыл кучу вариантов и все упирается в getActiveSheet(), getColumn() и прочее. Честно попытавшись сделать так, как указано в примерах, я столкнулся с тем, что программа ругается, мол "TypeError: Не удается вызвать метод "getActiveSheet" объекта undefined. (строка 13)." Попытался через вызов SpreadsheetApp - говорит, что не определен. Упорно не понимаю, в чем собственно дело. Помогите пожалуйста!

```
function onEdit(e) {
//Переменная now - возвращаемое значение
var now = new Date();
var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
//var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
return Utilities.formatDate(now, 'GMT+3', 'dd.MM.yyyy');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

На случай, если кто то окажется таким же чайником, как я. 
onEdit() хоть и идет как функция, в ячейку записываться не должен.

Answer (score 0):

Может, по нубский, но я делал так:

```
 cell = sheet.getRange(currentrowIndex,currentcolumnIndex);
 cell.setValue("=NOW()");
 now = cell.getValue();
 cell.setValue(now);
 cell.setNumberFormat("hh:mm")
```